# Writing C plugins for C and Java

Tags: java, c, plugins

for a networking project, with my team we have implemented two version of the program with a shell interface, one in C and the other in Java.

The C version is more advanced because we've added a plugin system for adding commands in the shell. The plugin programmer interface enable access to some functions of the main program for sending protocol messages accross the network.

We've developped some good plugins, and now we wonder if we can find a way to use the plugins written in C. After some research we found that it is possible to load native C code in Java using the JNI interface and we also found some examples, all quite basics using arithmetic operations and basic I/O.

One problem is that our C programmer plugin interface has functions like `send_message(char *type, char *format, ...)` which can be used by plugins to send message other the network. Basically it sends UDP messages to all the element of a `struct sockaddr_in` from the main program. This is a problem if we wan't use the same plugin in Java since the main program isn't running.

So my question is how to program a plugin interface and plugin programmer interface in C for plugins that could run in both C and Java, if that's possible?

Thank you

PS: Is it possible to write C functions that access to Java ressources?

Comment: This is possible but you'd have to write a "glue" layer to interface between the Java and C code, and probably isn't worth it.

Comment: What kind of glue would I apply ?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes, what you describe is possible, and JNI is mechanism for it.  The details depend in large part on the nature of the C code, and overall the question is far too broad if you are in fact asking about those details.  If you have a sufficiently specific question then we could take it up -- preferably as a separate question.

Comment: Yes you're right... Just regarding the case of `send_message` would it be an answerable question?

Comment: Or maybe more important, regarding to this http://hildstrom.com/projects/jni/index.html I can run java code in C instancing a JVM, but is it possible to access to an already created JVM (the one that runs the C plugin)?